# Quote macro for defining string

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to quote the "content" of a macro?
Something like the following code for printing the string "AAA".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _L 5
#define _QUOTE(a) #a
#define _TEXT AAA
#define _STRINGAAA _QUOTE(_TEXT)

const char STRINGAAA[ _L ] = _STRINGAAA;

int main(void)
{
    printf( "%s\n", STRINGAAA );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using identifiers that begin with an underscore character, especially macros, as they are reserved for the implementation.  In particular, the identifier `_L` is highly likely to conflict with internationalization macros found in system headers.  Of course, in your example, it would be best to omit the macro for the array length all together and just write `const char text[] = "AAA";` and have the compiler figure out the required number of bytes.  (It is actually 4, not 5.)  You can later refer to it as `sizeof(text)`.

Comment: ...It is actually 4, not 5... : that was because of tests I was doing...

Comment: My point is not whether it is 4 or 5 but that hard-coding things that the compiler could easily figure out itself is at best a waste of time and at worst introduces bugs into your program that are totally avoidable.

Comment: In fact it was one of your points. Following your suggestions, it is best for my program to write #define a_macro_name "aaa", then write const char a_const_char_name[] = a_macro_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a second set of macros to force macro argument substitution before stringization:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _L 5
#define _XQUOTE(a) #a
#define _QUOTE(a) _XQUOTE(a)
#define _TEXT AAA
#define _STRINGAAA _QUOTE(_TEXT)

const char STRINGAAA[ _L ] = _STRINGAAA;

int main(void)
{
    printf( "%s\n", STRINGAAA );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```