# using #define and # for stringizing to convert another macro constant to string

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

With reference to this question [Quote macro for defining string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918645/quote-macro-for-defining-string), Idea is that I want to print the value of a macro constant, say for the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define X 4
#define Tostring(x) #x
main()
{
    printf(Tostring(X));
}
```

It is printng `X` instead of 4, but with [Quote macro for defining string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918645/quote-macro-for-defining-string) I know how to correct it, but can someone explain what exactly is gong on here?

Comment: You missed a step in the question you quoted: https://ideone.com/eYC3dX

Comment: Please do not tag C and C++, these are different languages and answers may vary between both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print 4 as you wish you can one of these:

Stringizing the result:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define Tostring(x) str(x)
#define str(x) #x
#define X 4

int main()
{
            printf(Tostring(X));
}
```

or using function like macros to convert X to int:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define X 4
#define Tostring(x)(X)

int main()
{
            printf("%d\n", Tostring(X));
}
```

The first example is one of the examples that is given in [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing). There it is stated that two levels of macros shall be used if you want to stringize the result of the expansion of a macro. The result of the expansion is the following:

Tostring (X)
     -> Tostring(4)
     -> str (4)
     -> "4"

In the second example you are relating the argument of Tostring macro with the X from the `#define X 4` and thus you can print the value as an int.